# How to make IBM API Connect on-premises and IBM DataPower Gateway on EC2 work?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ibm-datapower

I'm running a DataPower gateway server (v. 7.2) on an AWS EC2 instance using the DataPower debian packages and API Connect 5.0.1 on-premises as a virtual server.

However, I can't seem to get it to work as intended. I can successfully publish an API but when trying to call it I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <env:Body>
         <env:Fault>
            <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
               <faultstring>Internal Error (from client)</faultstring>               
         </env:Fault> 
      </env:Body>
   </env:Envelope>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work or how to "debug" the error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Following is a log from the DataPower gateway:

```
time(descending)    category    level   domain  tid direction   client  msgid   message Show last   50  100  all
Wednesday, September 7, 2016
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405713    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405713            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405713            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405729    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405729            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:11 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405713            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405697    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405697            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405697            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405729            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405745    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405745            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:11 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405697            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:11 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405745            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:11 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405729            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:11 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405745            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:11 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  100447          0x80e0004e  loadbalancer-group (mgmt-lb): Standard health check failed - server down 'https://192.168.247.146:2443/v1/catalogs/status'
1:23:11 PM  multistep   error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  100447  health      0x80c00075  loadbalancer-group (mgmt-lb): External URL: 'https://192.168.247.146:2443/v1/catalogs/status' timed out.
1:23:11 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  100447          0x80e00625  loadbalancer-group (mgmt-lb): Connect to URL 'https://192.168.247.146:2443/v1/catalogs/status' timed out
1:23:11 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  100447          0x80e00049  xmlmgr (webapi): Host connection failed to establish: 192.168.247.146 : tcp port 2443
1:23:11 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  100447          0x00b30009  xmlmgr (webapi): Host connection could not be established
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405617    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405617            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405601    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405585    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405601            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405585            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405601            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405617            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:10 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405585            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:10 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405601            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:10 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405617            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:10 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405585            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:09 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405521    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:09 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405505    error       0x01130006  mpgw (webapi-internal): Failed to establish a backside connection
1:23:09 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405521            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:09 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405505            0x80e00126  mpgw (webapi-internal): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent
1:23:09 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405505            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:09 PM  mpgw    error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405521            0x80e00623  mpgw (webapi-internal): Cannot find the requested resource for the URL 'https://analytics-lb/x2020/v1/events/logevent'
1:23:09 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405505            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:09 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12405521            0x80e00048  loadbalancer-group (analytics-lb): DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error
1:23:08 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12618848    scheduled       0x80e00040  xmlmgr (webapi): url-open: Remote error on url 'http://127.227.158.245:2934/catalogs/v1/catalogs/gateway.xml'
1:23:08 PM  network error   APIMgmt_96F1E39EF5  12618848            0x80e00625  Connect to URL 'http://127.227.158.245:2934/catalogs/v1/catalogs/gateway.xml' timed out
1:23:07 PM  network error   APIMgmt_A0AABCC130  68463           0x80e0004e  loadbalancer-group (mgmt-lb): Standard health check failed - server down 'https://192.168.247.146:2443/v1/catalogs/status'
1:23:07 PM  system  error   APIMgmt_A0AABCC130  12405249            0x80e0027d  Unable to open URL 'store:///identity.xsl'
```

Comment: Log into the datapower and check the logs and/or activate the debug probe to see processing of the individual steps

Comment: @StefanHegny Added log excerpt to question. How do I activate the debug probe?

Comment: There might be enough information already in the log: `DNS Callback cannot resolve host 'analytics-lb': returning error` so it can't connect to the backside url `https://analytics-lb/...`  So maybe you start by setting DNS servers or a static host so the name can be mapped to an IP

Answer (score 0):

You need to add static hosts or a DNS server to the default domain Network Interface. 
DataPower can't find the host through the dns name. 
Another option is to use the IP address instead.